# configuring resolver to show my site as provider

Tags: hosting, nameserver, domains

Hey i want to show my website as a hosting provider. When we search for a domain it says who is hosting that domain . so i want to setup my domain as a provider. when users search for websites that use my nameservers.

here's the site:
http://www.whoishostingthis.com

so how do i configure my server to show as a provider?

Answer (score 1):

That is a simple web front-end to the [WHOIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WHOIS#Regional_Internet_registries) database and you'll need to be registered there as the actual owner of the ip-address your servers use, or rather the owner of the block of ip-adresses.  For most people and small companies that will be their Internet Service Provider as they won't have their own [provider-independent ip address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Provider-independent_address_space).